# Syntax error on token "***", AnnotationName expected after this token

Tags: java

i was going to set the Dog height under my code but it flagged it with the error above is there any fix for it, any {} im missing?

like the code is almost done, i checked all, it worked and tried adding dog's height and it threw me that syntax error

```
public class Dog
{
private int age;
private String name;
private String Color;
private int Height;
public Dog(int age,String name,String Color, int Height)
{
   this.age= age;
   this.name= name;
   this.Color = Color;
   this. Altura = Altura;
}
public String setDogName(String Name)
{
   this.name = name;
   return name;
}
public String getDogName()
{
   return name;
}
public String setDogColor(String Color)
{
   this.Color = Color;
   return Color;

}
{
   public int setDogHeight()
}
public int setDogAge(int age)
{
   this.age = age;
   return age;
}

public int getDogAge()
{
   return age;
}

public int computeDogAge()
{
   this.age=age*7;
   return age;
}
public String toString()
{
   String dogsname= "Dog's name:";
   String dogsage= "Dog's age:";
   String dogcolor= "Dog's Color:";
   return dogsname + name +"\t"+dogsage+age+"\t"+dogcolor+Color;
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
   Dog dog1 = new Dog (1,"sasha","red");
   Dog dog2 = new Dog (7,"karmine","green");
   Dog dog3 = new Dog (6,"dakota","blue");

   dog1.setDogAge(9);
   System.out.println((dog1));

   dog2.setDogName("shazam");
   System.out.println(dog2);

   System.out.println(dog3);

   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Dog's age in human years:");
   System.out.println(dog1.computeDogAge());
   System.out.println(dog2.computeDogAge());
   System.out.println(dog3.computeDogAge());
   
   if(dog1.age >dog2.age); {
       System.out.println( "sasha is older than karmine");

   }

   
}
}
```

the error appears from the line 28 to 31 with this code

```
}
{
    public int setDogHeight()
}
```

Comment: Compare `setDogHeight` with all the other `setXXX` methods above and below it. What's different about it?

Answer (score 1):

There were some smaller type errors:

- You forgot to change `altura` to `height`.
- There was a simicolon behind a method declaration's bracket.
- The `Dog`s created in `main()` don't follow your constructor.
- The curly brackets of `setDogHeight()` were placed around the method declaration.
- The attribute `name` in `setDogName()` was capitalized.

Here is the corrected code:

```
package com.company;

public class Dog {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private String color;
    private int height;

    public Dog(int age, String name, String color, int height) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setDogName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDogName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setDogColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setDogHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setDogAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getDogAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int computeDogAge() {
        this.age = age * 7;
        return age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String dogName = "Dog's name: ";
        String dogAge = "Dog's age: ";
        String dogColor = "Dog's Color: ";
        return dogName + name + "\t" + dogAge + age + "\t" + dogColor + color;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog1 = new Dog(1, "sasha", "red", 1);
        Dog dog2 = new Dog(7, "karmine", "green", 1);
        Dog dog3 = new Dog(6, "dakota", "blue", 1);

        dog1.setDogAge(9);
        System.out.println((dog1));

        dog2.setDogName("shazam");
        System.out.println(dog2);

        System.out.println(dog3);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Dog's age in human years:");
        System.out.println(dog1.computeDogAge());
        System.out.println(dog2.computeDogAge());
        System.out.println(dog3.computeDogAge());

        if (dog1.age > dog2.age) {
            System.out.println(dog1.name + " is older than " + dog2.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Some tips to avoid these problems:

- You can return a value you in a setter like `setDogName()`, but if you don't use that return value anyway, you can just make it `void`.
- Stick to the [code conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf), for example using lowercase characters for variable and method names.
- Don't store any information twice. In your `if`-statement in `main()`, you print out `"sasha is older than karmine"`. But the names of the dogs are already defined when you create them. Now, the program will not print `"shazam"` instead of `"karmine"`, eventhough you changed the name. Access the attribute instead (see code).
- Do not change code in getters like `computeDogAge()`. If you call that method the second time, it will multiply the age again. Instead, you can directly return `age * 7` (see code).
- If you format your code, you will not have any trouble with compile errors like this anymore. Use an IDE like [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/idea/) to format your code using `Strg`+`Alt`+`L`.